# How to return date format (f.e. mm/dd/yyyy) from a date (f.e. 06/30/2019)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm working on data validation in the SQL Server Database. 
I need to check if dates in the Table are populated in a valid format for specified Country.

Is there any function in SQL that will return a date format from a date?

For example: Date: **06/30/2019** What I need to get: **mm/dd/yyyy**

Thanks!

Comment: The `DATE` datatype doesn't have a format in SQL Server, it's a binary data. Unless you're storing it as a formatted string which is wrong.

Comment: Even if you unwisely stored dates as text, what format is `01/01/01`? Any of the components could be `mm`, `dd`, or `yy`. This is precisely why the native date/time types unambiguously store date and time internally as a numerical offset.

Comment: The fact that you state *"I'm working on data validation in the SQL Server Database. I need to check if dates in the Table are populated in a valid format for specified Country."* screams that you are storing dates as a `varchar`. Don't. `01/31/2020` is not **before** `12/31/2000`. **Always** use a datetype appropriate for your data; in this case you want `date`.

Comment: The problem is that dates were stored as strings instead of dates. You can't validate such values. There's no way to determine what `01/07/2019` means - January 7th or July 1st? What if the client application uses dashes or dots? Use a proper type like `date` instead. The *real* fix is to change the column to a `date`

Comment: The dates are always the last day of a month and year is always 4 digits, so there will be no issue such as 01/01/01, but that's a good catch though!

Comment: And of course, the (unfortunately still relevant 9.5 years after posted) article by Aaron Bertrand: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

Comment: So you're "ok" with the behaviour like `02/28/2019` being before `01/31/2010` @TheBvrtosz? On my calendar `02/28/2019` is about 9 years after `01/31/2010` , not the "month" after `02/28/2018`.

Comment: @TheBvrtosz there's no reason to use strings for such data. You don't have to perform any kind of check if you store `date` values instead of strings. Never mind the impossibility of sorting or performing range searches

Comment: @TheBvrtosz once you fix the field's type you can use a CHECK that verifies the value *is* the end of the month, eg with `MyDateField=EOMONTH(MyDateField)`

Comment: If you know, by some stroke of luck, that the string is guaranteed to match only one format, this is still not an easy thing to do in T-SQL. Essentially, use a huge `SELECT CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(DATE, '06/30/2019', 101) IS NOT NULL THEN 'MM/dd/yyyy' `, but then that does raise the issue of what you intend to *do* with the format once you have it, given that you cannot feed that string to `CONVERT` or `PARSE`. (You also still really can't distinguish separators this way, so that would need even more checks if you needed that.) This is much better solved *outside* SQL Server.

Comment: The point is, 
I receive dates from outside. 

The dates need to be formatted with respect to the country that is aligned to. 
So, for the united states 6th march of 2019 the proper formatting is: 06/30/2019
but for the spain it's 30/06/2019. All the dates are being stored as a DATE format not as a string. 
The problem is i need to validate if i receive dates with valid formatting for specific country.

Comment: @TheBvrtosz If the dates are stored in a column with the `Date` data type, they are not stored with their display format. If they are stored in a column with a string data type (char, nchar, varchar or nvarchar), then storing them in different formats is the worst possible thing you can do.

Comment: If you know the culture, then `TRY_PARSE(... AS DATE USING 'en-US')` could be your friend. It works with country codes too (i.e. just `en` or `es`) but that can be more ambiguous. You are still much better off demanding that callers only supply their data as `DATE` values in commands, and use client code to convert data if it's not (rather than using T-SQL to process raw text, which it's very bad at).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we've all mentioned in the comments, storing a date as a `varchar` in the database is the wrong idea. We also now know that all dates need to be the last day of the month (from the comments), so now we do have something to work with. Therefore, you could *fix* your table with something like the below:

```
--Create a new column to store old values
ALTER TABLE YourTable ADD DateString varchar(10);

--Update the new column and change the existing column to ISO (yyyyMMdd) format
UPDATE YourTable
SET DateSting = DateColumn,
    DateColumn = TRY_CONVERT(varchar(10), TRY_CONVERT(date, DateColumn, 101), 112);

--Change the data type of the datecolumn
ALTER TABLE YourTable ALTER COLUMN DateColumn date;

--Inspect "lost" data:
SELECT DateString
FROM YourTable
WHERE DateColumn IS NULL
  AND DateString IS NOT NULL;

GO

--Add the CHECK CONSTRAINT    
ALTER TABLE YourTable
ADD CONSTRAINT Date_EOMonth CHECK (DateColumn = EOMONTH(DateColumn));
```

If the `CHECK CONSTRAINT` fails to be created you have dates that aren't at the end of the month, so you can use the below statement to inspect them, or the statement after to update them all to the end of the month:

```
SELECT DateColumn
FROM YourTable
WHERE DateColumn != EOMONTH(DateColumn);

--Blanket Update    
UPDATE YourTable
SET DateColumn = EOMONTH(DateColumn);
```